# What is the sense of the equality sign =?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Sometimes in real analysis, we write an equality and specify that is true in the sense of the $L^2$ norm.
My question is, when in mathematics we write '=' and don't specify anything, what we really mean?
Do we mean uniform convergence, more than that, or less than that?

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not sure what you mean by equality in the sense of a norm. If you mean $x=y$ if and only if $\lVert x - y \rVert = 0$ then this is independent of your choice of $\lVert - \rVert$.

Comment: I mean, for example:
$f\in{L^2(0,\pi)}$ and S is its fourier series.
So we write $f(x)=S$.
I think in infinite dimension, it depends on the chosen norm, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: The $=$ in this case means that the infinite series converges in the $L^2$ norm, i.e. for every $\varepsilon>0$, we can find $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\|f-S_n\|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$, where we let $S_n$ be the partial sum of the Fourier series up to the $n$th place.

Comment: Exactly. My question is what means the general '=' sign.

Comment: Thanks for specifying, I didn't know we were takling about Fourier series.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318297/what-is-the-definition-of

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I see where the confusion is.  Let's clarify: generally speaking, the equality sign $=$ pretty much always means the same thing (two elements are the same in a given space).  It's the issue of *convergence* that changes.  This is best seen by two examples:

**Example 1:** Suppose I say that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 7$.  Now, one might say that this equation means that:

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - 2| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - 7| < \epsilon$.

So, one could *mistakenly* think, "Wow, that $=$ sign is hiding a lot of information.  That's a completely different kind of equality."  But it's not the $=$ sign that's doing it!  It's the limit itself.  In other words, we could have written it this way:

$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$ is the number such that

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - 2| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - \lim_{x\to 2} f(x)| < \epsilon$,

and this number, $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$, is (i.e. equals) 7.

**Example 2:** In a similar way, suppose $f_n$ are $L^2$ functions, and I say that $\sum_1^\infty f_k = g$ in $L^2$.  Again, this is best phrased like this:

$\sum_1^\infty f_k$ is the function such that

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $\Vert \sum_1^n f_k - \sum_1^\infty f_k \Vert_2 < \epsilon$,

and also $g$ is that same function $\sum_1^\infty f_k$ (almost everywhere).

**Summary:** The equals sign $=$ is the same thing you've always known and loved (except that it's taken relative to a given space).  What you have to understand is what **expressions** like $\lim f(x)$ and $\sum f_n$ really mean.

Comment: Thanks pal. You have cleared my grief.

Comment: I think this is misleading.  The equals sign really is playing a different role in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $L_2$.  If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, $a=b$ means that $a$ and $b$ are the same real numbers.  But if $f$ and $g$ are functions then saying "$f=g$ in $L_2$" is saying that $f$ and $g$, though they may be different set functions, belong to the same equivalence class; i.e. that $||f-g||_2 = 0$.

Comment: Also your second and third statement in grey have some issues.

Comment: Yes Antonio. After chosing this answer as an accepted answer I kept on thinking and I realized of what you are saying. Anyways this answer has been very helpful to clear my confusion.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Yes, I realized that I glossed over the distinction between, as you say, $\mathbb{R}$ and $L^2$ (though this is why I said "in a given space"). However, my sense was that this was not the distinction that was confusing to the OP.  But what did I get wrong in the second gray box?  I'll gladly edit, but I don't see the problem.

Comment: @JesseMadnick whoops, you're right, I misread.  The second box was fine.

Answer (score 13):

The relationship $f\sim g$ defined as $\|f-g\|=0$ is called an equivalence relationship.

In general, if $X$ is a set, an equivalence relation on $X$ is a subset of $R\subseteq X\times X$ which has the properties:

1. Reflexivity: $\forall x\in X:(x,x)\in R$
2. Symmetry: $\forall x,y\in X: (x,y)\in R\implies (y,x)\in R$
3. Transitivity: $\forall x,y,z\in X: (x,y)\in R \text{ and }(y,z)\in R\implies (x,y)\in R$

If we write $(x,y)\in R$ as $x\sim_R y$ then this means

1. $x\sim_R x$
2. $x\sim_R y \implies y\sim_R x$
3. $x\sim_R y \text{ and }y\sim_R z\implies x\sim_R z$

Now, given an equivalence relation on $X$, we can partition $X$ into something called equivalence classes, and we can construct a set $X/\sim_R$ and a map $\pi: X\to X/\sim_R$ such that $\pi(x)=\pi(y)$ if and only if $x\sim_R y$. We sometimes write $\pi(x)=\left<x\right>_{\sim_R}$ or just $\left<x\right>$ if the equivalence relation is known.

So, in your case, we start with $L^2$, and define an equivalence relation $\sim$ as above, and then construct $L^2/\sim$.

It is common to abuse notation, and instead of writing for $x,y\in L^2$ that either $x\sim y$ or that $\left<x\right>=\left<y\right>$, we just write $x=y$. This is lazy notation, but in cases like $L^2/\sim$, it is not a big deal.

You often want the equivalence relation to be nice. For example, in this case of $L^2$ and $\sim$, if $f_1\sim g_1$ and $f_2\sim g_2$ then $\|f_1-f_2\|=\|g_1-g_2\|$. Nice features of the equivalence relationship means that we don't have to take much care which $f$ we choose from an equivalence class in our proofs - if $\left<f\right>=\left<g\right>$ then the proof works the same using $g$ instead of $f$. However, we do have to prove that the equivalence relation is "nice" in this way.

For another example of the "niceness" of $\sim$ on $L^2$: If $f_1\sim g_1$ and $f_2\sim g_2$, then $f_1+f_2\sim g_1+g_2$. So we can define $+$ in $L^2/\sim$.

Comment: Thanks.
So when I write $x+1=\sin(x)$ which would be the relation of equivalence?

Comment: Well, $x+1=\sin x$ is probably not in the same vein - rather, it is an equation. You are meant to find some $x$ in a domain where the two functions are equal. That is a very different than saying the two functions are $\sim$ in $L^2$. So when you see that, you are meant to assume either that you are being asked "For what values of $x$ is $1+x=\sin x$?" or you are meant to take it as an assertion about a particular $x$: "Take an $x$ such that $1+x=\sin x$. Show that  $x\leq 0$."

Comment: And wouldn't be right to say that in this expression there is uniform convergence in the domain where the equality holds? Therefore the standard '=' is 'stronger' than an equality in the sense of uniform convergence.

Comment: @KaranArya In which expression?

Comment: $1+x=\sin(x)$ or any other equality. My problem is that I'm trying to understand the '=' sign as an indicator of some kind of convergence always.

Comment: @KaranArya: Don't do that. Convergence is a quite different thing from identity, and even if you apply the "abuse of notation" Thomas describes, "=" should only be used for things that are more like identity than they are like convergence.

Answer (score 8):

When mathematicians write the equality sign $=$, they officially mean just equality, i.e. $x = y$ means $x$ and $y$ are the same thing.

It is sometimes convenient to allow $=$ to have a slightly different meaning, but most frequently this boils down to properly understanding what is on either side of the equality. For instance, if you want write $f = g$ for equality in $L^2$, what you really mean is that you treat $f$ and $g$ as elements of $L^2$, and you are comparing these. Hence, the problem boils down to the question: what are the objects you are talking about? (which is not quite trivial, since the "same" function may belong to a lot of various function spaces, for example). Note that a purist would probably specify by adding after $f = g$ something like "in $L^2$" or "almost everywhere".

If you have a limit or a series (which is a limit in disguise) on either side, the real question is: how are you taking the limit? To make sense of a statement like "$f = \sum_n a_n x^n$" or some other series, you need to figure out in what space you are taking the sum. Once you know this, he equality is the equality in that space.

Comment: Very nice explanation. I can go delete mine now.

Answer (score 6):

Building on Jesse Madnick's excellent answer, one way of interpreting

> "$f = g$ in the sense of the $L^2$ norm"

is that what it really means is

> "$\langle f \rangle = \langle g \rangle$, where $\langle f \rangle$ and $\langle g \rangle$ denote that $L^2$ equivalence classes of $f$ and $g$ respectively"

but we're being lazy in our notation and using just the plain function symbols $f$ and $g$ to stand for their equivalence classes, in order to avoid an excessive profusion of brackets.

Or, alternatively, we could interpret $f$ and $g$ as *being* the the equivalence classes, and say that we're being lazy by using them elsewhere as functions without explicitly picking a representative function from each class.

Either way, this habit of using the same symbol to denote both an equivalence class and a representative member of it is common in many areas of mathematics, since it makes the notation much less cluttered.  It does, however, mean that we sometimes need to explicitly clarify in which sense we are using a particular symbol.